# Загрузка изображения в ckeditor

Tags: python, selenium

Как загрузить изображение в ckeditor ипользуя selenium+python?

Comment: Я так понимаю загрузка изображения происходит через html элемент
<input type="file"> или реализацию drag/n/drop. 
Через selenium и через отправку JS скриптов в консоль разработчика это реализовать никак, только костылями с помощью кликера или изворачиваться через запросы.
Под "изворачиваться через запросы" подразумевается, например, взять cookie файлы после авторизации, отловить нужный запрос и сэмулировать POST запрос через requests

Comment: Ты прав, стандартными методами это не решить

#driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input").send_keys('/home/qwerty/Downloads/123.jpg')

#driver.find_element_by_name("upload").send_keys("/home/qwerty/Downloads/123.jpg")

Comment: Нет, отправка изображений не так работает. 
Если упрощенно говорить, то запрос с картинкой отправляется в виде байтов, а не директории с изображением.
https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types#multipartform-data